# Force mypy to typecheck third-party package

Tags: python, mypy

I'm using a third-party package (in this case [jsonrpcserver](https://github.com/bcb/jsonrpcserver) though this problem could apply to other packages) that is fully type-aware, and even includes a `py.typed` file in its sources.

However, due to a packaging bug, the `py.typed` file is not installed.

As a result, mypy insists

```
error: Skipping analyzing 'jsonrpcserver.response': found module but no type hints or library stubs
```

Even though I can say for a fact that the module does have type hints.  Is there a way I can *force* mypy to analyze this package even if it's missing the `py.typed`?  I shouldn't have to create a stub library for this purpose since the package is otherwise type-aware.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a nice way to do that. There is some discussion in [this mypy github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8545) about introducing a flag for exactly this purpose, but it's not there yet.

A less nice way for now could be creating the `py.typed` file yourself before running mypy (mentioned [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8421)). Perhaps as part of a script that sets up the test environment or similar.

Getting the right path for that file:

```sh
python -c 'import jsonrpcserver; print(jsonrpcserver.__path__[0] + "/py.typed")'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue.  I'm using a workaround exactly like the above in my CI scripts for now!